# How to return fee in all PayPal transactions

Tags: magento, curl, paypal, nvp

Good Afternoon

I’m making a paypal integration with a Brasilian Magento Platform and I have to capture the fee returned by paypal

```
//---------//routine to recover the fee on database Paypal//--------//
        $nvp = array(

            //'TRANSACTIONID'            => '7W763566L0166562G',
            'TRANSACTIONID'               => $transactionId,
            'METHOD'                => 'GetTransactionDetails',
            'PWD'                    => 'UVAYAK9WMNPP75KA',
            'USER'                    => 'leonardoccleao_api1.gmail.com',
            'SIGNATURE'            => 'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AYlssmYYHWWmVugX7vy.se0mIMAM',
            'VERSION'                           => '84',

        );

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_URL , 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp' );
        curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false );
        curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 );
        curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_POST , 1 );
        curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , http_build_query( $nvp ) );

        $response = urldecode( curl_exec( $curl ) );

        $responseNvp = array();

        if ( preg_match_all( '/(?<name>[^\=]+)\=(?<value>[^&]+)&?/' , $response , $matches ) ) {
            foreach ( $matches[ 'name' ] as $offset => $name ) {
                $responseNvp[ $name ] = $matches[ 'value' ][ $offset ];
            }
        }

        $fee_amount = $responseNvp['FEEAMT'];//fee recovered

        echo $fee_amount;//I get to print the fee
        curl_close( $curl );
        //---------/end routine to recover the fee on database Paypal //--------//
```

I get the fee by giving to PayPal the transaction Id (txv_id) but it only works in some transactions. In some transactions PayPal returns fee = 0.

I made a script to fill a data table with a range of transaction but of the 40 transactions made through paypal I just got 2 fees. The transactions have the same product and the same price, but not always the same fee

I want know if PayPal has some another way to return this attribute

Answer (score 0):

On some transactions, for example when paying with your PayPal balance, there is no fee. This might be the reason.

Paypal fees: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/helpcenter/article/?currentIssueID=11927&topicID=11500006&m=TCI